# Airflow + AWS SES (HTTP API not SMTP one): error Invalid type for parameter Source, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'str'>

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-ses

I am trying to configure airflow to send an email using AWS SES(HTTP) email backend. The configuration is done according to https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/email-config.html. But I always get an error "Invalid type for parameter Source". This comes from AWS API where it validates source/from parameter should not be null. But, airflow email API does not accept the parameter code snippet below(ref: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/utils/email.py). So my question is how to send the source/from-email parameter. Is there any configuration parameter airflow config file or it takes from AWS IAM credential. I am using AWS IAM credential set with AIRFLOW__EMAIL__EMAIL_CONN_ID parameter in airflow.

```
def send_email(
    to: Union[List[str], Iterable[str]],
    subject: str,
    html_content: str,
    files: Optional[List[str]] = None,
    dryrun: bool = False,
    cc: Optional[Union[str, Iterable[str]]] = None,
    bcc: Optional[Union[str, Iterable[str]]] = None,
    mime_subtype: str = 'mixed',
    mime_charset: str = 'utf-8',
    conn_id: Optional[str] = None,
    **kwargs,
):
```

Comment: What version of Airflow are you running?

Comment: Its airflow v2.0.1

Comment: Well, I used the SESHook directly which is used by the EmailOperator internally, and passed the extra parameter and made it work. The other way would be to use a customized python class in the email_backend parameter. Default one is airflow.providers.amazon.aws.utils.emailer.send_email.

Comment: Hi, any chance you can share your [email] config? I'm hitting some similar issues with SES and Airflow

Comment: Hello @MenyIssakov, well I did not use email_backend, rather used SESHook. Its inside providers->amazon->aws->hooks>ses.py. It was simpler for me. Instantiate your SESHook with aws creds and call the send_email method. Something like  `ses_hook.send_email(mail_from, to, subject, html_data, None, cc)`

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while, but one of the main things I missed was that you have to restart the *scheduler*, not the airflow webserver (but, since my services are called airflow and airflow-scheduler, I forgot the first one is really just the webserver)

Here's an example of my airflow.cfg file:

```
[email]

# Configuration email backend and whether to
# send email alerts on retry or failure
# Email backend to use
#email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp
email_backend = airflow.providers.amazon.aws.utils.emailer.send_email
# aws_ses is a connection I created in the airflow web UI
email_conn_id = aws_ses
from_email = Name <me@example.com>
```

As for the AWS side, I set up an access key and secret (which I entered into the airflow web UI to create the aws_ses connection). I also did a few other things related to roles, though I'm not sure if they were needed.

I didn't get the same error you did, but I kept getting an error on sending the email so maybe this will help.